# CPU frequency stuck at low value after installing gnome extensions

Tags: gnome, battery, cpu, gnome-shell-extension

I have experimented with different gnome extensions to control the performance and battery life on my laptop. Notably, I installed and uninstalled these two extensions:

- [CPU Power Manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/945/cpu-power-manager/)
- [cpufreq](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/)

I partly run them at the same time, then uninstalled and reinstalled them. Now my CPUs are stuck at the minimum frequency and changing the governor has no more effect.

```
user@XPS:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz
cpu MHz     : 800.039
cpu MHz     : 800.035
cpu MHz     : 800.037
cpu MHz     : 800.026
cpu MHz     : 800.008
cpu MHz     : 800.036
cpu MHz     : 800.040
cpu MHz     : 800.028

user@XPS:~$ for governor in $(ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor); do cat $governor; done
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

How can I trouble-shoot this?

---

Here some more information:

The CPUs remain at 800 Mhz even under load. (I tested it running 0.A.D. with six bots on a large map.)

```
user@XPS:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate

user@XPS:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:3800000

user@XPS:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:800000

user@XPS:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*perf_pct
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:25
```

Comment: Start with what CPU frequency driver? Do `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver`. Next, what are the max and mins? Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq` and if your driver is intel_pstate: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*perf_pct`. then we'll go from there. Note: I never ever use any of those add on tools. Oh, and if you have no load at all (unlikely in a desktop (O.K. LapTop) with a GUI), you might well see 800 MHz, even in performance mode.

Comment: Yes if you give it no work the frequency is low. Try running a computation and rerun your command.

Comment: I added the above requested information. Even under heavy load the frequency remains constantly 800 Mhz.

Comment: If your processor is HWP capable, try to disable it. You could also try to disable the intel_pstate driver entirely, witch would then cause the acpi-cpufreq driver to be used. These are all  grub `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` options, `intel_pstate=disable` and `intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp`. I would very much like to understand your issue.

Comment: Actually, first try this `echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` and does that un-stick it? are there any indications of thermal events in any of your log files?

Comment: I tried all three options. 'intel_pstate=no_hwp' didnt change anything. 'intel_pstate=passive' set the scaling driver to intel_cpufreq and ' intel_pstate=disable' set the driver to acpi_cpufreq. But the CPU frequency remained 800 MHz even under load. (going to bed now).

Comment: `echo powersave | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

 Didn't un-stick it either.

Comment: Then it is likely something external to the OS is forcing low frequency. Typically problems with the AC adapter or battery or both. Dell is the worst for this, but I have heard of it with other brands also. You always ran `sudo update-grub` and then re-booted after each change, right?

Comment: Yes, I did run `sudo update-grub` everytime and as I wrote, changes in the driver took place.

Comment: It seems that the machine is no longer reactive to changes in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking different options in grub with no result, I booted a clean ubuntu image from USB. The CPU frequency was still at 800 Mhz indication that it wasn't OS related. A quick search yielded that this is a Dell safeguard mechanism to protect the laptop and is triggered by a thermal event, bad battery, or faulty charger. In my case, it was probably a thermal event I had at the same time I experimented with the above-mentioned extensions. My laptop failed to sleep and went full throttle in my rucksack sometime last week.

The solution was to unscrew the back-lid and disconnect the battery for >15 seconds. This resets the safeguard mechanism. After reboot the CPU is again following the intel_pstate settings.